# AttributeError in Sage in calling list()

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror, sage

I had some problem with error in Sage (I just cannot find a way to solve it)

Here is a code

```py
nb = 8
varl = [ c + str( p ) for c in 'xyz' for p in range(nb)]
B = BooleanPolynomialRing ( names = varl )
B.inject_variables ()
P.<p> = PolynomialRing ( B )
Byte.<t> = P.quotient_ring ( p^8 + p^4 + p^3 + p + 1)
X = B.gens()[: nb ]
Y = B.gens()[ nb :2*nb ]
x = sum ([ X [ j ]*t^j for j in range(nb)])
y = sum ([ Y [ j ]*t^j for j in range(nb)])

E3 = x*y
ep3 = E3.list()
latex(ep3)
```

and output

```py
Defining x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, z0, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7
Error in lines 12-12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cocalc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 1188, in execute
    flags=compile_flags) in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 489, in sage.structure.element.Element.__getattr__ (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4611)
    return self.getattr_from_category(name)
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 502, in sage.structure.element.Element.getattr_from_category (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4720)
    return getattr_from_other_class(self, cls, name)
  File "sage/cpython/getattr.pyx", line 389, in sage.cpython.getattr.getattr_from_other_class (build/cythonized/sage/cpython/getattr.c:2540)
    raise AttributeError(dummy_error_message)
AttributeError: 'QuotientRing_generic_with_category.element_class' object has no attribute 'list'
```

I don't understand, why it not working.
I tried to make it in cocalc.com and also in desktop version of Sage, but it didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `E3.list()`? E3 is an element of `Byte`, and I'm not sure how you are hoping to make a list out of it.

Comment: This code from https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/589.pdf page 4, list() should get the coefficients of each power of t in equation E3.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `E3.list()` doesn't work. Maybe it used to in Sage 6.7 when the cited paper came out, but it doesn't now. The following should work: keep everything you have up to and including `E3 = x*y`. At this point, `E3` is

```
x7*y7*t^14 + (x6*y7 + x7*y6)*t^13 + (x5*y7 + x6*y6 + x7*y5)*t^12 + (x4*y7 + x5*y6 + x6*y5 + x7*y4)*t^11 + (x3*y7 + x4*y6 + x5*y5 + x6*y4 + x7*y3)*t^10 + (x2*y7 + x3*y6 + x4*y5 + x5*y4 + x6*y3 + x7*y2)*t^9 + (x1*y7 + x2*y6 + x3*y5 + x4*y4 + x5*y3 + x6*y2 + x7*y1)*t^8 + (x0*y7 + x1*y6 + x2*y5 + x3*y4 + x4*y3 + x5*y2 + x6*y1 + x7*y0)*t^7 + (x0*y6 + x1*y5 + x2*y4 + x3*y3 + x4*y2 + x5*y1 + x6*y0)*t^6 + (x0*y5 + x1*y4 + x2*y3 + x3*y2 + x4*y1 + x5*y0)*t^5 + (x0*y4 + x1*y3 + x2*y2 + x3*y1 + x4*y0)*t^4 + (x0*y3 + x1*y2 + x2*y1 + x3*y0)*t^3 + (x0*y2 + x1*y1 + x2*y0)*t^2 + (x0*y1 + x1*y0)*t + x0*y0
```

So then do:

```
E3L = E3.lift()
[E3L.monomial_coefficient(_) for _ in E3L.monomials()]
```

This returns

```
[x7*y7,
 x6*y7 + x7*y6,
 x5*y7 + x6*y6 + x7*y5,
 x4*y7 + x5*y6 + x6*y5 + x7*y4,
 x3*y7 + x4*y6 + x5*y5 + x6*y4 + x7*y3,
 x2*y7 + x3*y6 + x4*y5 + x5*y4 + x6*y3 + x7*y2,
 x1*y7 + x2*y6 + x3*y5 + x4*y4 + x5*y3 + x6*y2 + x7*y1,
 x0*y7 + x1*y6 + x2*y5 + x3*y4 + x4*y3 + x5*y2 + x6*y1 + x7*y0,
 x0*y6 + x1*y5 + x2*y4 + x3*y3 + x4*y2 + x5*y1 + x6*y0,
 x0*y5 + x1*y4 + x2*y3 + x3*y2 + x4*y1 + x5*y0,
 x0*y4 + x1*y3 + x2*y2 + x3*y1 + x4*y0,
 x0*y3 + x1*y2 + x2*y1 + x3*y0,
 x0*y2 + x1*y1 + x2*y0,
 x0*y1 + x1*y0,
 x0*y0]
```

You could also do `latex(...)` applied to the whole thing, or you could do

```
[latex(E3L.monomial_coefficient(_)) for _ in E3L.monomials()]
```

to get the list of LaTeX expressions for the coefficients.

Alternatively:

```
E3L = E3.lift()
E3L.list()
```

produces the list of coefficients but in increasing order of degree rather than decreasing: it returns

```
[x0*y0,
 x0*y1 + x1*y0,
 x0*y2 + x1*y1 + x2*y0,
 x0*y3 + x1*y2 + x2*y1 + x3*y0,
 x0*y4 + x1*y3 + x2*y2 + x3*y1 + x4*y0,
 x0*y5 + x1*y4 + x2*y3 + x3*y2 + x4*y1 + x5*y0,
 x0*y6 + x1*y5 + x2*y4 + x3*y3 + x4*y2 + x5*y1 + x6*y0,
 x0*y7 + x1*y6 + x2*y5 + x3*y4 + x4*y3 + x5*y2 + x6*y1 + x7*y0,
 x1*y7 + x2*y6 + x3*y5 + x4*y4 + x5*y3 + x6*y2 + x7*y1,
 x2*y7 + x3*y6 + x4*y5 + x5*y4 + x6*y3 + x7*y2,
 x3*y7 + x4*y6 + x5*y5 + x6*y4 + x7*y3,
 x4*y7 + x5*y6 + x6*y5 + x7*y4,
 x5*y7 + x6*y6 + x7*y5,
 x6*y7 + x7*y6,
 x7*y7]
```

Comment: E3L = E3.lift() not fits me, but I installed Sage 8.2 instead and now it works.
Thank you for your help:)

Comment: I'm glad it works. Note that 8.2 is about a year old; the most recent version is 8.7.